# Check if a list of integers increments by one

Tags: c#, linq, list

Is there a way, with LINQ, to check if a list of integers are "sequential" - ie 1,2,3,4,5 or 14,15,16,17,18?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do this via [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
bool sequential = values.Zip(values.Skip(1), (a,b) => (a+1) == b).All(x => x);
```

This works by taking each pair of values, and checking to see if the second is 1 more than the first, and returning booleans.  If all pairs fit the criteria, the values are sequential.

---

Given that this is a *list* of integers, you can do this slightly more efficiently using:

```
bool sequential = values.Skip(1).Select((v,i) => v == (values[i]+1)).All(v => v);
```

This will only work on sequences which can be accessed by index.  Note that we use `values[i]`, not `values[i-1]`, as the `Skip` call effectively shifts the indices.

Comment: +1. I think it also can be done with Aggregate (just keep difference) to avoid iterating sequence multiple times... I'll try to write it later as answer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My second option only iterates once, but relies on the sequence being a list.  I can see how to do it with `Aggregate`, but only if you make your lambda have nasty side effects... :(

Comment: Added the sample... No side effects needed (since Aggregate creates new TAccumulate on each step), but it is not the prettiest thing.

Answer (score 16):

```
bool isSequential = Enumerable.Range(values.Min(), values.Count())
                              .SequenceEqual(values);
```

Comment: I don't know why this wasn't selected as the answer. Its brilliantly simple.

Answer (score 2):

One more option is to use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) to iterate sequence only once.

Note that unlike `All` suggested by Reed Copsey `Aggregate` can't stop in the middle when condition fails...

```
var s = new int[] {3,4,5,6}.ToList();

var isSequential = s.Aggregate
  (
      new {PrevValue = 0, isFirst = true, Success = true} ,
      (acc, current) => 
          new {
                  PrevValue = current,
                  isFirst = false, 
                  Success = acc.Success && (acc.isFirst || (acc.PrevValue == current - 1))
               }
  )
  .Success;
```

Fancier version would be to have iterator that carries previous value along or special code that would split iterator on "First and the rest" allowing to implement Reed's solution with single iteration for any enumerable.

Comment: Added `ToList()` since the question was about a list. I wanna the continuation of fun and fancier versions!

Comment: +1 This works - but it churns a lot of memory for large lists, and can't short circuit on success...  I still prefer either of my options (my 2nd, in particular, is more efficient if you know it's a List<T>).

Answer (score -1):

If you already know that the numbers you have in your list is **unique**, and also **sorted**, then the simplest check for sequential is just

```
lst[lst.Count - 1] - lst[0] == lst.Count - 1
```

Assume atleast 1 element in list.